# how to get a number form value and turn it into string javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to turn a number I get from a form into a string and combine it with another string, but I receive this:

```
windows.location='multiSet?type=multi'Number
```

instead I want to get this:

```
windows.location='multiSet?type=multiNumber'
```

Note that the difference is the position of the ' mark is before `Number` and I want it after it..

All i see in other post is how to put a string as a number not viceversa.

```
var singleMultiContainer = document.getElementById("singleMultiContainer");
var singleMultiValue = singleMultiContainer.value;
var nextButton = document.getElementById("nextButton");
var multipleSetWindow = "window.location='multiSet.html?type=multi'";
var singleSetWindow = "window.location='SampleInfo.html?type=single'";
var containerCuantity = document.getElementById("containerCuantity");

function setContainers(){
    singleMultiValue = singleMultiContainer.value;
    containerCuantityValue = parseInt(containerCuantity.value);
    if (singleMultiValue == "multi"){
        //alert("Multi");
        document.getElementById("nextButton").setAttribute("onclick", multipleSetWindow+containerCuantityValue);

    } else if (singleMultiValue == "single") {
        document.getElementById("nextButton").setAttribute("onclick", singleSetWindow);
    }
}

singleMultiContainer.onchange = function(){
    setContainers();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `setAttribute` to define event handlers. And you don't need to parse the value as you want to put it back in a string.

Change

```
document.getElementById("nextButton").setAttribute("onclick", multipleSetWindow+containerCuantityValue);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("nextButton").onclick = function(){
      window.location='multiSet.html?type=multi'+containerCuantity.value;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that but wouldn't that make the code a little bit sloppy for later maintenance?

Comment: @Ch32k0 No, that's how proper javascript code is written. Don't write event handlers as strings which the browser must evaluate, directly make the event handler a function, this is much cleaner and you avoid many problems, for example with quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and tip. GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: The page takes a lot to load for it to be simple form. Any suggestion

Comment: @Ch32k0 Delete it, start over?

Comment: @Ch32k0 You might want to consider the newer and better `addEventListener` (needs a simple shim in IE8-) - it'll add a listener rather than replace the action. It's the best practice and and the right thing to do.